# I want to remove the Start/Stop button in Anythingslider, but leave the rest of the navigation

Tags: javascript, html, anythingslider

I'm using AnythingSlider (fun toy) as a website where the panels are the site's pages. As such, I want to disable and remove the Start/Stop button but leave the rest of the navigation. I'm under the impression that it's part of the navigation and can't be optioned out. If that's correct, how do I do it?

Actually, I want to move the navigation to the top right of the panel, as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the examples here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

The 2nd example does not have the button.  If you read the source:

```
        $('#slider2').anythingSlider({
            width               : 600,       // if resizeContent is false, this is the default width if panel size is not defined
            height              : 350,       // if resizeContent is false, this is the default height if panel size is not defined
            resizeContents      : false,     // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
            autoPlay            : false,     // This turns off the entire slideshow FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not
            navigationFormatter : formatText // Format navigation labels with text
        })
```

Look at autoPlay.  It is clearly responsible for the start/stop functionality, including the button.

Comment: Just noticed that... Thanks for your input.

Comment: You could always do: `$('.start-stop').hide();`

Comment: This option is for older versions of AnythingSlider. Asaf has the answer for latest verison @ https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider

Answer (score 3):

Completely removing the "start/stop" button:

```
buildStartStop: false
```

(no hiding, no tricks, simply removed)

Answer (score 1):

Hiding play/stop button, but still working with autoplay:

```
startText           : '',
stopText            : '',
```

Answer (score 0):

Call of the dogs. It is an option:

```
autoPlay : false,
```